# Why is my react navigation not working on android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Recently I merged some changes from a colleague and these changes have React Native Navigation setup in it. After installing all the dependencies and setting up everything, When I run the app, I get this error that says

**com.app.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity**

Apparently, the error is coming from the following file

```
react-native-navigation\lib\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativenavigation\react\NavigationModule.java
```

### How to reproduce

I am not really sure how to reproduce this error because I don't know what's causing it in the first place. However, the only other unexpected behavior was that my Android Studio or react-native run-android both were failing gradle build when I first added all the required dependencies. The reason for failure was kotlin-android and even though I can confirm that from the build.gradle files of the repository that the required settings exist, still I had to add the relevant required config to my main applications android/gradle.build and android/app/gradle.build
Apparently this solved the issue with now react-native run-android running successful gradle build.

The repository has the following dependencies config

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61"
```

Despite the presence of above, my gradle builds were failing and complaining about android-kotlin so I added the following dependencies config to my app's android/gradle.build

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2')
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
```

Notice the difference in versions of the gradle (This gradle version came by default with RN 0.62) and kotlin-gradle-plugin. I don't know, but could this be the cause of the issue?

[image]

[image: The error seems to be coming from here]

I am using latest version **5.5.1** for @react-navigation/native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Actually the problem was being caused by another package that was just added to the project and wasn't setup and being used. The package that was causing the issue was https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation which I didn't notice it was there and it apparently wasn't properly configured.

Comment: react-native-navigation is totally another navigation lib different from react-navigation/native. It also got me confused at first. Delete it solved the problem.